# Splitting or joining  text with jQuery on click

Tags: jquery, text, event-handling, onclick

I would like to split or join text using a click of the mouse. As part of a project I am doing.

When the user clicks a character, a word boundary is marked or un-marked after the current character, depending on the current state.

Currently, each word of my text is contained in a span:

```
<span class="word">te</span> <span class="word">xt</span>
```

I would like a click on the `e` to result in:

```
<span class="word">text</span>
```

and clicking the `t` in the original text should result in:

```
<span class="word">t</span> <span class="word">e</span> <span class="word">xt</span>
```

I assume this is possible to do with the jQuery `replaceWith()` function, but am not quite sure how to detect the individual characters (ideally, I would like to avoid an extra span on each character, since my texts might be relatively long)?
Would appreciate any help with my implementation needs and/or suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Brilliant, smells like University assignment innit? B-) google some apis like `split` & `map`

Comment: No, I am not a student and it is not an assignment :) It is for a personal project related to splitting Asian languages (particularly Chinese) into words.

Comment: Why do you want to split? you may just add an empty space `&nbsp;`

Comment: Weird example, it starts with two words: te and xt. Also I still can't tell what you're supposed to click to split or join things.

Comment: I would like to create some simple editing functions for Asian text, directly on a web-page (split/join words and rotate classes). Because I want to mark up some of the words in the text, I need each word to be contained in a span.

Comment: How does clicking on an `e` inside a word `te` cause it to become a new word by collapsing right with the word to its right? Your markup needs to represent spans going from chars to words or something. Right it transforms from words into words and I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that's exactly what you want but maybe it'll help:

I used a textarea and the [jCaret](http://www.jquery-plugin.buss.hk/my-plugins/jquery-caret-plugin) plugin to detect the cursor position, then insert or delete spaces on click:

**JS:**

```
$('textarea').bind('click', function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    if (v) {
        var p = $(this).caret().start;
        var ls = $(this).val().split('');
        if (ls[p] == ' ') {
            ls.splice(p, 1);
        } else {
            ls.splice(p, 0, ' ');
        }
        $(this).val(ls.join(''));
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/JrHQB/

---

Without textbox:

**JS:**

```
$('#t').html('<span>' + $('#t').text().split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>').find('span').click(function() {
    if ($(this).next().text() == ' ') {
        $(this).next().remove();
    } else {
        $(this).after('<span> </span>');
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/v4dxf/

Comment: If this is not what the OP wanted, it sure as heck sounds like what he asked for.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the result that I wanted (except for the fact that the current jsfiddle makes it possible to add multiple spaces, but this is a minor detail that I am sure is easy to fix), but I'd like to know how I can implement it without a text field (spans for each character is fine if it is necessary).

Comment: @CarlJohan Updated my answer with a version using spans. I think you can't get the clicked character reliably without using spans around each one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect and process a click on an individual character unless that character has its own DOM element[1], so you will need additional spans. The only exception is inside a TextField or TextArea, where the click moves the cursor before triggering the OnClick handler. There the current cursor position will contain the information you need and is available in the OnClick handler.

[1] This isn't entirely true, but it's too hard to bother with if the alternative is even remotely acceptable.

Comment: Assuming each character has its own span, e.g. <span class="char"> in my above example, do you have any pointers on how I can do it?

Using a text field would give me some limitations on what rich formatting I can use in the field, right?